# Why C# does not modify fields directly in the managed heap like C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, clr, boxing

As I see in the book *C# via CLR* writtern by Jeffrey Richter, when talking about boxing and unboxing/copying operations, Mr Richter shows a demo:

```
public static void Main() {
    Point p; // Point is a value type defined before
    p.x = p.y = 1;
    Object o = p; // Boxes p; o refers to the boxed instance

    // Change Point's x field to 2
    p = (Point) o; // Unboxes o AND copies fields from boxed
    // instance to stack variable
    p.x = 2; // Changes the state of the stack variable
    o = p; // Boxes p; o refers to a new boxed instance
}
```

In order to change the value of a boxed instance, we need to do an unboxing-then-boxing-again operation, the performance is not that good.

To avoid my misunderstanding of book, here is the exactly what the autor says:

> However, in some languages like C++/CLI, they allow you to unbox a
>   boxed value type without copying the fields.Unboxing returns the
>   address of the unboxed portion of a boxed object (ignoring the
>   object’s type object pointer and sync block index overhead). You can
>   now use this pointer to manipulate the unboxed instance’s fields
>   (which happen to be in a boxed object on the heap). For example, the
>   previous code would be much more efficient if written in C++/CLI,
>   because you could change the value of Point’s x field within the
>   already boxed Point instance. This would avoid both allocating a new
>   object on the heap and copying all of the fields twice!

Here comes my question: Why C# does not do what C++/CLR does? Is there some other important issues prevent C# team to do this "redundant" design and make the performance not good as we expect? What's behind this "unnatural" behavior?

Comment: If you're using a `Point` inside a class as a field, it will be on the heap. Boxing and unboxing is a bad example whether it's on the heap or not. Boxing is done when you store a valuetype value in a reference type. I think it has to do with, a valuetype will be initial on the stack. When you box it, it will store the reference _(pointer)_ on the stack and the data on the heap.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen First, I think you misunderstanding my question; Second, boxing will keep the data on the stack and copy it, not just the "pointer".

Comment: Actually it makes just as much sense to call the C++/CLI behaviour "unnatural".  In C# the best practice is to design and use value types as immutable so the whole 'efficiency' issue of mutating them doesn't come up. No reason to add a probably complicating feature when you don't need or even want it. Would it be possible to maintain memory-safety with such a feature?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Emm... I think your answer may be right. But could u give a more detailed one, like giving a specific example of how this feature affects memory-safety? Thanks.

Comment: No, notice that I ended that part with a '?'.

Comment: C++/CLI has syntax that allows you to refer to a *typed box*: `System::Int32^` is a boxed instance of `System::Int32`. C# lacks such syntax, so the only thing it lets you do is copy the value when unboxing. That's not a big issue BTW, if you use boxing you've already lost the performance battle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# and C++ have somewhat different philosophies. Unlike C++, which is a system programming language, C# wants to save the programmer from dealing with memory allocation and pointers, so it tries to hide some of the details involved in memory management. In C#, value types are equivalent to primitive types and structs in C++. They are just a sequence of bytes somewhere in memory. In C++, you can easily declare a pointer to an int or struct, wherever it may reside, but C# won't allow that. This indirection is hidden inside the boxing/unboxing mechanism.

"Boxing" roughly means that the value type is created on the heap, and an object reference to this memory is silently returned. Unboxing simply reverses this indirection. Boxing/unboxing occurs automatically whenever you use a value type in a context where a reference type is expected - for instance, when casting an integer to an Object:

```
Int32 i4Value = 12345;
Object pValue = (Object) i4Value;
```

Casting an Object reference back to an integer automatically unboxes the value, i.e. copies it from the heap to a normal value.

The C++/CLI team did quite some wizardry to allow C++ programmers to use low-level C# features. This is one example. They exploit the C++ syntax to let you do some things a C# programmer isn't even aware of, because they happen somewhere behind the scenes.

Frankly, I've never been in need to use this special boxing/unboxing trick of C++/CLI, although I'm writing C++/CLI code all day long. However, there are certainly some situations where there's no other way - for instance, when interfacing some weird 3rd-party C# component that cannot be changed, because there's no source code available.